# Ansible looping through values specified in a file

Tags: loops, ansible

Trying to get a hang of ansible loops as a beginner. I've got a role for setting up multiple users with their respective attributes. I can loop through the values successfully when the values are specified within the task file but struggling to call the values if they are kept in a different file.

Content of "/roles/myusers/tasks/useradd.yml

```
- name: Add serveral users
  user:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    group: sftp
    groups: sftp
    state: present
    uid: "{{ item.uid }}"
  loop:
    {{ users }}
```

Content of "/roles/myusers/vars/main.yml"

````
---
users:
  - { name: 'testuser1', uid: '691' }
  - { name: 'testuser2', uid: '692' }```
````

Content of Content of "/roles/myusers/tasks/main.yml"

```
---
- import_tasks: useradd.yml
```

Please can someone shed some light? My understanding is that when the values are kept in /var/main.yml file there doesnt appear to be a reason to use "include_vars", "include" and etc..? Admit that I haven't spent enough time going through the documentation. Looks to be it isn't the easiest thing to read. TIA guys.

Answer (score 1):

Quotation is missing. Try

> loop: "{{ users }}"

Comment: Thanks so much Vladimir. That did it. :) By the way how do I use a condition there? For an instance create those 2 users only when some condition matches? I know you are supposed to use when butwhere do I specify the condition in /vars/main.yml?

Comment: You can specify [conditions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html) in the tasks.